# Change Civilization and Leader name in Civilization V Multiplayer?

Tags: civilization-5

The last time I started a game with my friend we couldn't change our Civilization and Leader names in a multiplayer game that I hosted.

Is there a way to change them besides being able to do that in a single player game?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't select a Civilization?

Comment: I could select the Civilization itself, but not their custom name and custom Leader name.

Comment: Is anyone able to help? Thanks... I've been looking for answers on other forums and couldn't find them.

Comment: I don't know about this feature in particular, but in the interest of "balance" quite a bit of customization is disabled in multiplayer, such as exceeding the normal number of civs based on map size (IE, 8 for Standard).

Comment: If you go to set up a single player game, choose a Civilization and a Leader, you can see the Edit option in the lower right part of your Civilization's information. That's where you change your Civilization name. You could, for example, name it Skyrim and name your leader Ulfric Stormcloak. There doesn't seem to be the option in Multiplayer set up.

Comment: It should automatically load you into the appropriate Civ when you load a multiplayer game back up. If it does not, then the file could be corrupted.